# The shortest total length of wire that can be used with a weight.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, applications

> Suppose a weight is to be held $10 ft$ below a horizontal line $AB$ by a wire in the shape of a $Y$. If the points $A$ and $B$ are $8 ft$ apart, what is the shortest total length of wire that can be used?

I am not sure how the diagram would look like.

And I will probably need help after the diagram is drawn.

Sorry, I did not know how I should name my title.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Between three arbitrary vertices of a triangle a Fermat point minimizes the total distances from one point and this $Y-$ node is the Fermat-Torricelli point. The sum of distances is minimum when dynamic equilibrium is established between three equal and (angularly) equi-spaced forces acting on the  $Y-$ point node at $120^{0} $ between taut strings.

[FermatPoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point)

In the diagram below half the weight hangs either on smooth pulleys at nodes $(A,B)$ or act along taut strings through fixed pegs.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could we do it using derivatives? I am not quite sure how to solve this.. @Narasimham

Comment: The derivation of Fermat point is given in wiki and in many other sources. but results of physics,are more powerful imho than  indirect mathematical solution. If you get hold of  book $  The Science of Soap Films , Soap Bubbles $  by  Cyril Isenberg this view presents itself more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

For Y shape, the total wire length is minimal if the three legs meet at $120^\circ$ angles. Hence the two top legs are both 4 ft times $\frac{\sqrt 3}2$ = $2\sqrt 3 $ ft long and the node is half of that below the top line, i.e., the vertical leg is $10-\sqrt 3$ ft long.